# ChromeDriver - headless option causes WebDriver to crash, when applied over added extension

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

Our framework uses “basic authenticator” extension that automatically takes care of authentication dialogs. The problem is that when attempting to run tests in headless mode, chromedriver crashes with following error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://paomkgjogbncmncdnconbommejfdhaoh/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://paomkgjogbncmncdnconbommejfdhaoh/_generated_background_page.html

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(“authenticator”));
options.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't accept extensions in [headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5).

Consider switching the extensions off, or using Firefox.